# Information about assembly creator / compiler?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

Is there any way I can find the information on who created or built a .NET assembly? (name, Visual Studio license used to build the assembly, etc.)

I do not have access to the source code; I only have access to the binaries and several files used to build the projects (.manifest, .pdb, .application, .config).

### Here's the long story (more details)

The reason I'm asking this is because I work in forensics, which is computer science applied to law enforcement. During a search warrant, I acquired a rogue .NET application that does fraud. We'd like to know who created it.

It's a simple .NET 4 application, probably built with Visual Studio 2010 (I see tons of references to version 10). I do not have acces to the source code, but I do have access to the assemblys for both C# projects (a .exe and a .dll) with their respective .manifest and .config files, and one .dll dependency (Microsoft for POS 1.2). I also have a .application file which seems to be a click-once deployment, but when I click on it, it says the .deploy file is missing. I also have access to the .pdb file for both assemblies (the .exe and .dll).

I decompiled the .exe and .dll with IL Spy. IL Spy was able to generate the source code succesfully from the application's IL instructions. I was able to compile succesfully (after a minor tweak), and study the code. But, there are no trace and no comments describing who the creator is. My guess is that .NET doesn't put comments in the assembly when it compiles. The only comments I found were the ones documenting the class methods (parameters, description, etc.). I also found no evidence in the .accdb (Access database) that is used with the .NET application using OleDB / ADO .NET.

I did see the file names used to build the assemblies with the .manifest files. It's all written in C# files on a Q drive letter... interesting, but this doesn't get me anywhere... (unless I'm missing something!)

Also, I heard Microsoft can check wether or not you used a valid license to build an application... is there a place where the license or SKU or something is stored, when someone builds? If it's true, I could ask Microsoft for license information, with the proper legal documents.

For now, I'm checking all of the files in a hex viewer in case I see a name, an ip address, or something that may give me a hint (like a code repository or something). I'm also checking the images embedded in the assembly. But for now, I found nothing...

Comment: I think you are out of luck. That is, I don't believe any of the information you are after is recorded in the binaries. You can verify this yourself by binary comparing the binaries of the same test project compiled with two different Visual Studio installations. Incidentally, you get the most low-level disassembly of .NET assemblies with ildasm - the disassembler that ships with the .NET framework - ILSpy may hide certain details from you in its attempt to make the output more readable for the traditional user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I will definetly try that test and see what difference there are in the binaries. Just like you, I think like that I'm out of luck. (that's why I asked) I'll also try looking at ildasm, and other decompilers like Redgate's and telerik's.